# How To Write Readable If Statements For Input's Validation?

Tags: php, if-statement, readability, code-readability

I'm encountered silly, but still significant problem. I'm creating validation for "Sign Up"-like page. I need to check that inputted values aren't harmful and fit my needs. Thanks to Fuel framework it's easy enough. Next... I need to check also that username or e-mail isn't already taken. I have written methods that do the job. But my problem comes when I need to write all "if statements".

This is what I have exactly right now. I'm not sure that's the correct way. I could write it all with "if's" and a lot of levels (nesting, I guess). I could use "if/else..if" there. What would you use?

```
if ( $validation->run() === true ) {

    if ( Diesel::usernameExists( $username ) === false ) {

        $error = 'This username is already taken! Try again...';

    }

    if ( Diesel::emailExists( $email ) === false ) {

        $error = 'This e-mail is already taken! Try again...';

    }


    if ( !isSet( $error ) ) {

        Diesel::signUp( $username, sha1( $password ), $email );


        Session::set_flash( 'notification', 'You have been successfully signed-up! Thanks...' );
        Session::set_flash( 'location', 'sign-in' );

        $this->response->redirect( 'notification' );

    }

} else {

    Session::set_flash( 'error', 'There was something wrong with validation! Try again...' );

    $this->response->redirect( 'sign-up' );

}
```

My goal, in other words, is to:

1) Check that inputted content aren't harmful and fits my needs (`$validation->run()`),

2) Step by step... isn't username already taken (`usernameExists()`)?

3) Isn't e-mail already taken (`emailExists()`)?

4) There could be more...

Application don't need to go further to step #2 if step #1 is false, for example. After that I need to have string that contains error message, but, you know, each step's message is different. Then I could pass the message to display it (if there is a message)! Of course, I can write code that works, but I'm looking for best-practices... and I have to follow DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid!) principles to keep my code readable and easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: Here's the outcome: http://pastie.org/1904127 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use if then else if, that would make the most sense I think.
That way if the first if is true that is all it will do,
otherwise it will go to the next.
Which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make validation methods out of those?

http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/validation.html check under "Extending Validation class", that way they'll be run when running validation. You can set the error messages as is described under ["Error Messages"](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/validation.html#errors)
(Btw you can add any class, the current controller or a model as well, using `$validation->add_callable('classname')` where `classname` can be both a class name or an object instance)

Comment: Thanks, Jelmer. Will try to do that! =]